# multiselect dropdown in excel using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is there any way to add multiselect dropdown in excel generated using PHPExcel.

I am able to add dropdown to select only one value in excel cell using below code:

```
        $mp_category_validation = $sheet->getCell("A2")->getDataValidation()
            ->setFormula1("'categories'" . '!$A$1:$A$50')
            ->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST)
            ->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION)
            ->setAllowBlank(false)
            ->setShowInputMessage(false)
            ->setShowErrorMessage(true)
            ->setShowDropDown(true);

    $sheet->setDataValidation("A3:A1048576", $mp_category_validation);
```

What are the required changes to make multiple values select from the dropdown, if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not allow multiple entries in the same cell, but it does allow a single delimited string to be put in a cell. VBA code (not supported by PHPExcel) would be needed to translate the users (multiple) selections into a delimited string.